# ASP.NET: Doesnot download Parallel content

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net application, how its possible to download all png,css JavaScript and other resources parallel.

Because i am monitoring using Fiddler and found that content is downloaded one after another.

Comment: How are you verifying that the resources aren't downloading in parallel?  Are you using the "Timeline" tab? Did you remember to turn on streaming mode in Fiddler? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/streaming.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually more of a browser (client) behaviour in accordance to the specification in HTTP 1.1. The guideline is to limit simultaneous downloads to *two per hostname*.

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/

While you may be able to alter your browser's settings to download more per hostname, that is only your machine and not that of others' in the Internet wilderness. One way to trick clients in downloading more simulatenously is to designate your web resources into different hostnames, like images stored in http://images.yoursite.com. But you may wanna to test this and balance it out, as per the article's suggestion.

Comment: FWIW, all current-version browsers (FF3.5, IE8, Chrome, etc) set the limit to 6 connections-per-host for HTTP/1.1.

Comment: supposing everybody has upgraded ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try AJAX for that as usually there are 5 allowed server/client http connections you could theoretically use them all at once.

However I guess you will take little advantage of this, unless you have really big (or many) css and javascript files.

Not sure if this will work on images or other files.

Comment: In IE at least, the same connection limits are enforced for requests from XMLHTTPRequest.